# What is the Ideal way to spoof files in nginx (alias, try_files or rewrite)

Tags: nginx, php, rewrite, alias

I'm trying to spoof file location by sending long url to the server, the server translate it to the proper php file and return the result, example:

I send a link like this:

```
http://example.com/fakelocation/123/456/789
```

I want the server to translate it like this:

```
http://example.com/myfile.php?arg=123&arg2=456&arg3=789
```

I have tried for several hours with no luck, also the third arg should be optional.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: To prevent direct access to some files, isn't that obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working like this:

```
rewrite ^/fakelocation/(\w*)/(\w*)/(\w*)? /myfile.php?arg1=$1&arg2=$2&arg3=$3 last;
```